# how to invoke a trigger manually in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there a way to invoke triggers manually using apex code. (not by updating field values for the record using ui or code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you need to run logic contained in triggers in a non-trigger context, factor the code into a separate service class and call it from a trigger handler. The service class can then be consumed in other contexts throughout your org's Apex codebase.

This is best practice regardless; triggers should generally contain no logic and simply call a handler framework, which further delegates business logic into other classes.